# what to do if we want javascript to be executed first then the php post method i.e submitting

Tags: php, javascript

For example: I want to accept or reject a photo.

The input button for accept and the form is:

```
<form method="post" action="viewRequests.php">
    <input type="submit" onClick="showAlertBox()">
</form>
```

`showAlertBox()` is a javascript function which shows a confirmation dialog with *Yes* or *No*. If I choose *No* then the form submission should not be triggered.

what to do in this case

Comment: Just a suggestion: jQuery is a great tool for such things, it offers a wide variety of options to handle situations like this: you can put an event handler on form submit, on button click etc. And jQuery UI also provides you great dialogs for confirmations and everything else :)

Answer (score 4):

Your Javascript function should return `false` if you do not want the form submission to be triggered.

Eg:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showAlertBox() {
        var answer = confirm ("Some yes/no question to the user");            
        return answer; // either true or false
    }
</script>

<form action="submit.php">
    <input type="submit" onClick="return showAlertBox()">
</form>
```

Comment: sir this line <input type="submit" onClick="return showAlertBox()"> is not working fine!

It gives red line under "return showAlertBox()"

Comment: ignore it. it won't matter. i tested the code. if you don't believe, copy the above to a html file and test it.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this way:

```
onsubmit="return showAlertBox();"
```

the showAlertBox function could be like that:

```
function showAlertBox()
{
   return confirm('validate');    // confirm returns TRUE on "OK"
}
```